Run JMH in dry-run mode
I am working on fixing a bug in kotlinx.benchmark, which wraps JMH. Development is made much slower because the tests actually run the benchmarks, which for what I'm doing, is not important. I just need to verify that JMH loads the options and correctly selects the benchmarks, but I do not actually need JMH to run and produce benchmarks.
What would be ideal is a way of forcing JMH to run in a dry-run mode, where it loads all benchmarks, but doesn't actually run them. For each benchmark it could return a fake result, or even a '0ms' result. Is something like this possible?
Running JMH
Here's how kotlinx.benchmark runs JMH at the moment.
kotlinx.benchmark invokes JMH via the org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner class in JvmBenchmarkRunner.kt.
JvmBenchmarkRunner is perhaps more complicated than it seems, but at its core, it's just building JMH Options and then running them, like this:
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode
import org.openjdk.jmh.results.format.ResultFormatType
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder

fun main() {
  val options = OptionsBuilder()
    .warmupForks(3)
    .forks(2)
    .mode(Mode.Throughput)
    .resultFormat(ResultFormatType.TEXT)
    // (more options)
    .build()
  
  val runner = Runner(options)
  runner.run()
}

I'm coding in Kotlin/JVM, but the situation is also applicable if using JMH in Java.
Potential solutions

Maybe there's a way of injecting a class that will override an existing JMH class, so that the tests never get launched?
How does JMH test itself? Is there an internal 'integration test mode' where benchmark execution is disabled? Maybe there's an system property that will disable execution of the actual the tests?

While it is possible to override the timings to be very low, e.g. 1ms, so that the test runs (almost) instantly, this is not desired as it prevents testing that the correct parameters are passed to JMH.

You could extend or modify the org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner class to include a "dry-run" mode by intercepting the execution and returning immediately after the benchmark discovery phase.

I think Ahmad has it right. The issue is that the run function in org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner is performing both the compiling of the benchmarks and then running them. If this were split into two separate functions, it would be easy enough to just call runner.compileBenchmarks() (for example -- if that function existed) instead of runner.run() in JvmBenchmarkRunner.kt.

Agree with Ahmed's solution , other option is to extend BenchmarkHandler and override methods  benchMarkStarted , benchMarkFinsihed, and handleError and this  Set benchmarkHandler in runner (runner.setBenchmarkHandler(DryRunBenchmarkHandler()))

This is what you need!
This is how I run JMH (Java Microbenchmark Harness) in a dry-run mode, where it loads all benchmarks but does not actually execute them, you can modify the way you invoke the Runner class. The goal is to intercept the execution after the benchmark discovery phase and return immediately without executing the benchmarks.
Step 1, Create Custom Runner Class:
You will need to create a custom runner that extends the existing Runner class from JMH. This custom runner will override the method responsible for executing the benchmarks.
Step 2, Override Execution Method:
In your custom runner, override the method that executes benchmarks run(). Instead of running the benchmarks, simply log or print out that the benchmarks have been discovered and return fake results or 0ms results.
Step 3, Modify Options:
When building your options using OptionsBuilder, ensure that you set any necessary flags or parameters that might be relevant for your dry-run mode.
Step 4, Use Custom Runner:
Replace instances of Runner with your custom runner in your benchmarking code. This way, when you call runner.run(), it will execute your overridden logic instead of running actual benchmarks.
Step 5, Compile and Run:
Compile your project and run it as usual. The output should indicate that benchmarks were loaded but not executed.
An example I use in my project.
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder
import org.openjdk.jmh.results.Result

class DryRunRunner(options: Options) : Runner(options) {
    override fun run() {
        // Simulate loading of benchmarks
        println("Dry run mode activated: Benchmarks loaded but not executed.")
        // Here I could return fake results if needed
    }
}

fun main() {
    val options = OptionsBuilder()
        .include(".*") // Include all benchmarks or specify as needed
        .build()

    val dryRunRunner = DryRunRunner(options)
    dryRunRunner.run()
}


Thanks for the proposal. However, it doesn't compile: run() needs to return Collection<RunResult>. Returning an empty list compiles, but results in JMH reporting zero benchmarks, which results in a failure downstream. Creating fake results is not trivial: JMH doesn't provide a way to obtain the requested benchmarks (although this can be worked around by calling list() with a custom outputter that collects the logged benchmarks). Even if the benchmarks are available, it's rather complicated to create a RunResult :(
